# ng-submit VS post form submit

Tags: angularjs

in the usual javascript form submit , what happens is that when i do the post the element names and values automatically are sent in the HTTP request to the server without me having to collect each one of them .

what I have noticed in angular form submits is that is not the case . based on [ng-submit example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) I have to collect each ng-model i have in the view into my controller and I have to do that in the submit function I write .

**My question** 
isnt there a way where I can collect everything from the view without having to refer to all of the ng-models in my controller ?

**Why ?**
there is this case where the form elements are dynamically drawn from a directive and its not very practical to refer to each when they are so many .
Any advice ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on app to app. If yours is a SPA then you have to make sure you use `ng-submit` and submit the form.

When you add dynamic elements to a form if you make sure you also add the `ng-model` accordingly then you dont have to worry about them. It will be part of the form submission.

I think what you can do is, all the form fields(even dynamic elements) can be maintained in an object e.g. `formData` and then add all the models into this object. Now in the submit method you can read all the form elements values (event the dynamic elements value) using `formData` object.

Whenever you add a dynamic element make sure it is added to `formData` object

E.g.

```
<input ng-model="formData.field1" type="text">
<input ng-model="formData.field" type="text">
```

Inside submit method you can get the form field vlaues using `$.param($scope.formData)`

Comment: yes its SPA , what i'm missing is that these ng-models i added , do i have to refer to each of them and get their values ? or will they be automatically sent to my controller submit function when i add ng-submit="submit()" ? @ShakarSangoli